# Database tuples in list

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, tuples

I have a program that runs a math test for students and then stores their scores in a database which can be read later to sort the classes and read previous student scores.

It works fine for the first time when the first score is inserted into the database, but when the second score is inserted I can see that `[(6,), 6]` is in the database. I don't understand why one is a tuple and the other is an integer (I'm not very familiar with tuples). Why can't I (or how can I) have it so that when the list is read from the database it returns `[6,6]`.

The code is such that there will always be 3 scores per student. This is the function below that writes the scores to the database.

```
def scoreText(name, classNo, score): 
    myFile = sqlite3.connect("scores.db") 
    c = myFile.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT score FROM scores WHERE name = (?) AND classNo = (?)', (name, classNo,)) 
    scores = c.fetchall()
    print(len(scores))

    if len(scores) == 0:
        print(scores)
        c.execute('INSERT INTO scores(score, name, classNo) VALUES(?,?,?) ', (score, name, classNo,))       
    elif len(scores) == 3:
        del scores[0]
        scores.append(score)
        #scores = ', '.join(map(str, scores))
        print(scores)
        c.execute('UPDATE scores SET score = (?) WHERE name = (?) AND classNo = (?)', (score, name, classNo,))
    else:
        scores.append(score)
        print(scores)
        c.execute('UPDATE scores SET score = (?) WHERE name = (?) AND classNo = (?)', (score, name, classNo,))

    myFile.commit()
    myFile.close()
    scoreText("jason", 1, 6)
```

Comment: `if len(scores) == 0:` then why join the (no) values together and print them?! Could you at least narrow the issue down to one of the branches - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry that, was just a temperary comment

Comment: i specified; how can i return it as [6,6] instead of [(6,),6]